# How can you performance test a Blazor component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

Is there a way to benchmark individual components performance?

For "normal code" you'd use something like benchmark .NET but I'm not sure that this is an accurate representation of a components performance when running inside an app, maybe it is for a server app and not for a WASM one?

I'd like to find a way to test performance of the base components in our library to avoid regressions and make optimisations as needed.

Has anyone done anything like this or able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: The performance of a component is dependant on so many factors, I'm not sure "Testing" it's performance is very meaningful.  You can use "BUnit" with timing to check performance in specific conditions.   Components are in general just `RenderFragment` delegates run by the `Renderer`.

Comment: Is it not worth testing them with, for example, a focus on memory consumption for each component?

Comment: Yes, if that's what you want to test.  Check out BUnit, though I'm not sure what hooks you have to check specifics like memory consumption, etc.  There'll probably mocking required which doesn't quite reflect true under load conditions.